# How to look at sql generated by EntityFramework when Count is used

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

When I have a query generated like this:

```
var query = from x in Entities.SomeTable
            select x;
```

I can set a breakpoint and after hovering cursor over query I can see what will be the SQL command sent to database. Unfortunately I cannot do it when I use Count

```
var query = (from x in Entities.SomeTable
            select x).Count();
```

Of course I could see what comes to SqlServer using profiler but maybe someone has any idea how to do it (if it is possible) in VS.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If you work on SQL Server, you can use Profiler.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173799(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: LINQPad is a wonderful tool to help in these and many other situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToTraceString()`:

```cs
ObjectQuery<SomeTable> query = (from x in Entities.SomeTable select x).Count();
Console.WriteLine(query.ToTraceString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Database.Log` to log any query made like this :

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // Your code here... 
}
```

Usually, in my context's constructor, I set that to my logger (whether it is NLog, Log4Net, or the stock .net loggers) and not the console, but actual logging tool is irrelevant.

[For more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 and above, you can use the following before your query:

```
context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

I've found this to be quicker than pulling up SQL Profiler and running a trace.
Also, this post talks more about this topic:
[How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)